# KeystoneJS form builder ideas?

Tags: forms, mongodb, keystonejs

I'm switching to keystoneJS as my CMS of choice. I'm exploring the options to create a form builder, so clients can create their own contact forms.

Nothing really comes to mind how to manage this with KeystoneJS and Mongo. I'm hoping anyone here can give a nice direction.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [formBuilder](http://formbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to create and render forms in your frontend. What you would probably do is save the form data on your MongoDB model, then pull from the model and supply it to the frontend when the form needs to be displayed. I don't know how I feel about saving raw HTML in your model, though, so I would tread carefully in that regard. Since there's probably no set length to your forms (the number of questions to be asked), that might be the only way to do it.

Comment: so you suggest using a different tool to create the form and save this in my mongodb?

Comment: Saving raw HTML in your model is never a good idea. One alternative you have it to use the formBuilder to just create your forms, then parse through the generated form and save just the important stuff as a JSON. e.g. `[{type: "select", options: ["array", "of", "options"], name: "testSelect"}, {type: "text", name: "name"}]. I personally use [caolan/forms](https://github.com/caolan/forms) for server-side form creation and rendering (it also gives you a lot of front-end control), but making the form itself is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

we used something like this

Lists:

- QuestionType (Text, LongText, Number, Date, SingleOption, MultipleOptions, SingleOptionOther, MultiOptionsOther)

  - refs to QuestionValidation
- Options
- Question

  - refs to QuestionTypes
  - refs to Options (in case is one othe OptionTypes)
- QuestionValidation
- Answers

  - refs to Question
  - refs to Options (in case is one othe OptionTypes)